# Java Matcher. Return several entries from one sequence

Tags: java, regex

For example I have following regexp: `\d{2}` (2 digits). And when I using

```
  Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("\\d{2}").matcher("123");
  matcher.find();
  String result = matcher.group();
```

In result variable I get only first entry, i.e. `12`. But I want to get ALL possible entries, i.e. `12` and `23`.

How to achieve this?

Comment: call `find()` in a loop ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You'll need the help of a capture group within a positive lookahead:

```
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("(?=(\\d{2}))").matcher("1234");
while (m.find()) System.out.println(m.group(1));
```

prints

```
12
23
34
```

Comment: (+1) simple and elegant solution! Looks awesome.

Answer (score 1):

That's not how regular expression matching works.  The matcher starts at the beginning of the string, and each time it finds a match it continues looking from the character following the *end* of that match - it will not give you overlapping matches.

If you want to find overlapping matches of an arbitrary regular expression without needing to use lookaheads and capturing groups you can do this by resetting the matcher's "region" after each match

```
Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile(theRegex).matcher(str);

// prevent ^ and $ from matching the beginning/end of the region when this is
// smaller than the whole string
matcher.useAnchoringBounds(false);
// allow lookaheads/behinds to look outside the current region
matcher.useTransparentBounds(true);

while(matcher.find()) {
  System.out.println(matcher.group());
  if(matcher.start() < str.length()) {
    // start looking again from the character after the _start_ of the previous
    // match, instead of the character following the _end_ of the match
    matcher.region(matcher.start() + 1, str.length());
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

some thing like this

```
^(?=[1-3]{2}$)(?!.*(.).*\1).*$
```

Test and experiment [here](http://www.rubular.com/r/ClZkpeGiQs)